# What part of speech is "do not," in, "Dude, if you do not sweep the floor, then...'

Tags: parts-of-speech

So, i'm doing a project for school, writing a letter, and figuring out what part of speech each word is, and i'm having difficulty with "do not" and "to take" in, "I will start 'to take' more of your chicken...". I would also like help with "for now", "But, for now, i will stay."

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Please add to your question **why** you are having difficulty: what do you think the answer should be and why you are uncertain that that is the answer. You should also show your own research. This allows others to guide you in the right direction rather than just giving you the answer. "Teach a man to fish..."

Comment: Part of speech only applies to individual words, and it doesn't tell you much anyway, especially if they only give you 8 choices. Once you get beyond single words, you're involved with phrases and clauses of various kinds (and their fragments).  _Do not_ is a fragment from a verb phrase, and _to take_ is a fragment from an infinitive clause. _For now_ is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: This would definitely get a better reception on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Part of speech only applies to individual words, and it doesn't tell you much anyway, especially if they only give you 8 choices. Once you get beyond single words, you're involved with phrases and clauses of various kinds (and their fragments).  *Do not* is a fragment from a verb phrase, and *to take* is a fragment from an infinitive clause. *For now* is a prepositional phrase.